# Free Lie sum vs free Lie product

Tags: lie-algebras, free-product

I am confused of definition of Free Lie sum and Free product of Lie algebras? May you please give some examples and an explicit definition of them?

Comment: What is the Free Lie sum?

Comment: indeed when I was studying an article I saw a result as follows: Let $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ be Lie algebras such that $dim L_{k} >1$ and let $L= L_{1}* L_{2}$ be their free sum , then $L$ has faithful irreducible representation. I searched for the "free sum" but I do not find any proper definition?

Comment: See articles of Shirshov and Kukin about "the free sum" and "the free product" of Lie algebras, with or without an amalgamated subalgebra [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02218584). The use of "sum" and "product" is sometimes mixed, for example, for "semidirect sums" or "semidirect products" of Lie algebras (because in group theory we have products, in the theory of algebras sums).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free Lie sum, or the free product of Lie algebras is defined, for example, [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.704.5278&rep=rep1&type=pdf), in section $6$, Definition $6.4$, as ususal with a universal property. It is denoted by $L_1\ast L_2$. Shirshov has given the first linear basis for the free product of Lie algebras.